# How can I display the first few line of a file with updates?

Tags: tail, head

When watching the last few lines of a text files for changes, I can use `tail -f` to continue updating my display. How can I achieve the same thing with `head`? Is there some solution which behaves like `head -n 10 -f <filename>`?

Comment: Maybe the `watch` command will do what you want?  `watch head -10 filename`; that'll refresh the screen every so often (2 seconds default) and run the `head -10 filename` command each time

Comment: In this scenario new lines are appended to beginning, not end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `watch` linux command executes a program periodically.  Maybe you can use this command with the firsts 10 lines for getting the result of command `head`.

Example:

```
watch head -10 <filename>
```

I hope can help you.

Comment: By default, `watch` run every two seconds, so if you want to achieve a similar behavior of `tail -f` you can alter the interval with `-n`. e.g. `watch -n .2 head -10 /var/log/messages` for a more ¿in-real-time? output

Comment: This answer is correct, but using `/var/log/messages` is not a good example, since that file should be `tail`ed.